# Instantiation within loop - primitives and objects

Tags: memory, instantiation

To make this language agnostic let's pseudo code something along the lines of:

```
    for(int i=0;i<=N;i++){
        double d=0;
        userDefinedObject o=new userDefinedObject();    

        //effectively do something useful
        o.destroy();
    }
```

Now, this may get into deeper details between Java/C++/Python etc, but:

1 - Is doing this with primitives wrong or just sort of ugly/overkill (d could be defined above, and set to 0 in each iteration if need be).

2 - Is doing this with an object actually wrong? Now,I know Java will take care of the memory but for C++ let's assume we have a proper destructor that we call.

Now - the question is quite succinct - is this wrong or just a matter of taste?

Thank you.

Comment: This is highly language-dependent, and I'm not sure which part of your question is the "this" in "doing this with primitives". If you're talking about declaring it inside the loop instead of outside, that's good. If you want each iteration to start with `d` freshly initialized to 0, declaring it inside the loop is the best way to do that. It will not cause a performance hit.

Comment: For the second part, you shouldn't need to explicitly call the object's destructor in C++, Java, Python, or most popular languages. (In C, you would need to explicitly destroy it.) In a GC'd language, the GC will destroy the object for you. In C++, you should declare it on the stack or handle it through a `std::unique_ptr`, and C++ will call the destructor for you.

Comment: The "this" is the instantiation within the loop as the title of the question suggests. Thank you for pointing that out if it is otherwise not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Garbage Collector will take care of any memory allocation without a reference, which means that if you instantiate on each iteration, you will allocate new memory and lose the reference to the previous one. Said this, you can conclude that the GC will take care of the non-referenced memory, BUT you also have to consider the fact that memory allocation, specifically object initialization takes time and process. So, if you do this on a small program, you're probably not going to feel anything wrong. But let say you're working with something like `Bitmap`, the allocation will totally own your memory.

For both cases, I'd say it is a matter of taste, but in a real life project, you should be totally sure that you need to initialize within a loop